# How to efficiently control the visibility of multiple textboxes

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to do a program where the user can control the dimension of the input matrix and provide the necessary textboxes according to the desired dimension of the matrix. With my current lines of codes, this will probably reach a thousand lines despite the simplicity of the function. Is there a way to write this more efficiently? The boxes should show up every time "Load" is clicked.

```
If (RowDisplay.Text = "1" And ColumnDisplay.Text = "1") Then
            Ta11.Visible = True
            Ta21.Visible = False
            Ta31.Visible = False
            Ta41.Visible = False
            Ta51.Visible = False

            Ta12.Visible = False
            Ta22.Visible = False
            Ta32.Visible = False
            Ta42.Visible = False
            Ta52.Visible = False

            Ta13.Visible = False
            Ta23.Visible = False
            Ta33.Visible = False
            Ta43.Visible = False
            Ta53.Visible = False

            Ta14.Visible = False
            Ta24.Visible = False
            Ta34.Visible = False
            Ta44.Visible = False
            Ta54.Visible = False

            Ta15.Visible = False
            Ta25.Visible = False
            Ta35.Visible = False
            Ta45.Visible = False
            Ta55.Visible = False
        ElseIf (RowDisplay.Text = "2" And ColumnDisplay.Text = "1") Then
            Ta11.Visible = True
            Ta21.Visible = True
            Ta31.Visible = False
            Ta41.Visible = False
            Ta51.Visible = False

            Ta12.Visible = False
            Ta22.Visible = False
            Ta32.Visible = False
            Ta42.Visible = False
            Ta52.Visible = False

            Ta13.Visible = False
            Ta23.Visible = False
            Ta33.Visible = False
            Ta43.Visible = False
            Ta53.Visible = False

            Ta14.Visible = False
            Ta24.Visible = False
            Ta34.Visible = False
            Ta44.Visible = False
            Ta54.Visible = False

            Ta15.Visible = False
            Ta25.Visible = False
            Ta35.Visible = False
            Ta45.Visible = False
            Ta55.Visible = False

        End If
```

Comment: Put all group of textboxes on a panel and then use `For Each txt In panel1.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox) txt.Visible = False Next`

Answer (score 0):

While I probably wouldn't recommend using all those `TextBoxes` in the first place. If you're going to do it that way, put them all in the same `Panel`, `TableLayoutPanel` or `FlowLayoutPanel`, then you can do this:

```vb
Private Sub DisplayTextBoxes(count As Integer)
    For i = 0 To myContainer.Controls.Count - 1
        myContainer.Controls(i).Visible = (i < count)
    Next
End Sub
```

If, for instance, you call that with a `count` of 2, the controls at index 0 and 1 will have `Visible` set to `True` and the rest will have `Visible` set to `False`.